# Finding mistakes in a given code block (extension of classes, person / student)

Tags: java, oop

In the following code block, there are several (intended) mistakes, and it is my task to find them and to explain whether the mistakes lead to problems while compiling the code or at least to some logical problems.

```
public class Person {

  private String name;

  public Person(String name) {

    name = name;

  }

  public String toString() {

    return "Name: " + name;

  }
}

public class Student expands Person {

  private int Nr;

  public Student(String name, int Nr) {

    name = name;

    Nr = Nr;

  }

   public String toString() {

   return toString() + " Nr: " + Nr;

  }
}
```

As far as I see it, the first mistakes is in the fourth row of the class `Person`. While `name = name`shouldn't lead to a compiling error, it should give logical problems since the formal parameter of the constructor `name` overlays the object variable `name` that we defined beforehand. The actual code would be `this.name = name`.

Besides that, I don't see any problems in the class `Person`.

The first mistake in the class 'Student' is the keyword `expands`, which should be `extends` instead. It should lead to a compiling error.

In the constructer Student, we write `name = name`. I'm not sure whether this will lead to a logical / compiling error or not. Maybe someone can me help out on this one? Anyway, we should call the super class here by writing `super(name)` instead since the `name` of the student is already given in the superclass `Person`.

Once again, we want to write `this.Nr = Nr`.

Last but not least, we don't want to return `toString() + ...`, because, well, i guess this calls the method `toString()` infinitely often and leads to a stack overflow.

Anything that I missed?

Comment: Already 2 downvotes after five seconds? Did anyone read my actual post?

Comment: not only did nobody read your question, nor did anybody read this comment of yours.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3990767

Comment: It's just an old exam question and I tried to solve it with paper and pen. That's not forbidden, isn't it? It's not a homework question.

Comment: Also Nr should be nr, not really a biggie, but you sure don't want avoid making such mistakes

Comment: While it's not a mistake, for bonus points you could also add that in a proper Java program, we should use @Override when we override stuff like toString().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis is correct.

You missed only one error in the constructor of `Student`

```
public Student(String name, int Nr) {
    name = name;   
    Nr = Nr;
}
```

Changing it to

```
public Student(String name, int Nr) {
    this.name = name;   
    Nr = Nr;
}
```

will generate a not compilable code because in the super class `name` is a private field, so not visible in the class `Student`.

**Note:** while it is not an error naming the variable `Nr` with upper N is against common best practice for variable namings. A variable or a method should start with a lower letter. A class or interface should start with upper letter.

---

@Julian, not only writing

```
public Student(String name, int Nr) {
    super(name);
    this.Nr = Nr;
}
```

will work, but **is also necessary**. Because the super class doesn't expose a default constructor. So the class `Student` needs explicitly call the constructor of super class in this way.

Comment: also the toString() implementation should look like return super.toString() + " Nr: " + Nr;

Comment: @MicheleDaRos the op already found the error in this line. Removing the toString() is enough, also calling the super is another option. It is not possible to see what is the real intent of the coder, so finding the error and showing how is possible to correct it for me is enough.

Comment: yes, but by removing toString() it will not print the "name" field. Since it is an exam question, may be that the teacher wants to test if the student knows about calls to super

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, as I said, it would be fine to write `super(name)` here, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In constructor of Student first line always calls default constructor of parent class. In this case Person class.

Since person class don't have default constructor (with no arguments) student constructor throws error.

Avoid this either create default constructor or call defined parameterized constructor. This should be first line. Something like,

```
public Student(String name, int Nr) {
  super(name);
  name = name; // This don't make sense. Its like assigning name to name itself
  Nr = Nr;    // This is same as above. Has no effect.

}
```

Also you are right about StackOverflowError in case of recursive call to toString.

Cheers!!!

Comment: @JimmyB : It will compile, because that name is argument passed to the Student constructor.